# passing yaml database from perl to python and vice versa

Tags: python, perl, yaml

I have a YAML database that was created by `perl` and contains some advanced features such as `perl` objects, `perl` code, and pointers.
 
I would like to manipulate the database in Python and return it to Perl, but without losing the Perl objects, as the Perl side needs them.

So far, I was able to read it on the python side and convert the `perl` objects to Python `dict`, but it lost some of the marks, such as the object type and the `perl`/code

my code:

```py
def construct_perl_object(loader, tag_suffix, node):
    return loader.construct_yaml_map(node)

def construct_perl_object_none(loader, tag_suffix, node):
    return loader.construct_scalar(node)

# yaml parsing definition
yaml.add_multi_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:perl/code', construct_perl_object_none)
yaml.add_multi_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:perl/hash:multi_task', construct_perl_object)
yaml.add_multi_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:perl/hash:single_task', construct_perl_object)

with open (<input file>) as fp:
    db = yaml.full_load(fp.read())
    print(yaml.dump(db))
```

input file:

```yaml
#YAML_OBJ
---
name: main
recipe: &1 !!perl/hash:multi_task
  name: 'pb_smb_verif_seahawk1.verif '
  parent: ~
  post_run: ~
  pre_run: ~
  tasks:
    - &2 !!perl/hash:single_task
      name: default_regcheck_test
      parent: *1
      post_run: ~
      pre_run: &3 !!perl/code |
        {
            my($task) = @_;
        }
    - &4 !!perl/hash:single_task
      name: reg_illegal_addr_test
      parent: *1
      post_run: ~
      pre_run: *3
  tasks_by_name:
    default_regcheck_test: *2
    reg_illegal_addr_test: *4
rel_work_dir: pb_smb/main
```

output:

```yaml
name: main
recipe: &id001
  name: 'pb_smb_verif_seahawk1.verif '
  parent: null
  post_run: null
  pre_run: null
  tasks:
  - &id002
    name: default_regcheck_test
    parent: *id001
    post_run: null
    pre_run: "{\n    my($task) = @_;\n}\n"
  - &id003
    name: reg_illegal_addr_test
    parent: *id001
    post_run: null
    pre_run: "{\n    my($task) = @_;\n}\n"
  tasks_by_name:
    default_regcheck_test: *id002
    reg_illegal_addr_test: *id003
rel_work_dir: pb_smb/main
```

**update**
I was able to solve the object types by manipulating the `perl` object tags to be `python` tags, but I couldn't solve the `perl/code` issue..
I tried to replace `!!perl/code |` with `!!str |` but when I dumped it back, it converted the whole code to single line

my code:

```py
file: my_yaml.py
import yaml

class multi_task: pass

class single_task: pass


def manipulate_perl_to_python(in_str):
    in_str = in_str.replace("!!perl/hash:", "!!python/object:my_yaml.")
    in_str = in_str.replace("!!perl/code |", "!!str |")
    return in_str


def manipulate_python_to_perl(in_str):
    in_str = in_str.replace("!!python/object:my_yaml.", "!!perl/hash:")
    return in_str


def full_load(in_str):
    in_str = manipulate_perl_to_python(in_str)
    return yaml.full_load(in_str)


def unsafe_load(in_str):
    in_str = manipulate_perl_to_python(in_str)
    return yaml.unsafe_load(in_str)


def dump(stream):
    return yaml.dump(stream, width=1000, indent=2)


def dump_to_perl(stream):
    txt = dump(stream)
    txt = manipulate_python_to_perl(txt)
    return txt

-------
import my_yaml
with open(<input_file>) as fp:
    txt = fp.read()
    db = xpipe_yaml.unsafe_load(txt)
    print(xpipe_yaml.dump_to_perl(db))
```

this part of the `yaml` code

```yaml
      pre_run: &3 !!perl/code |
        {
            package commands_lib;
            use strict 'refs';
            my($task) = @_;
            $DB::single = 1;
            my $wa_path = $task->get_context_param('wa_path');
            if (not defined $wa_path) {
                $task->update_status('FAILED', 'could not find workarea');
                return;
            }
            $task->add_cmd_arg('--wa_path ' . $wa_path);
        }
```

converted into:

```yaml
    pre_run: "{\n    package commands_lib;\n    use strict 'refs';\n    my($task) = @_;\n    $DB::single = 1;\n    my $wa_path = $task->get_context_param('wa_path');\n    if (not defined $wa_path) {\n        $task->update_status('FAILED', 'could not find workarea');\n        return;\n    }\n    $task->add_cmd_arg('--wa_path ' . $wa_path);\n}\n"
```

Comment: Why not just do it all in perl?

Comment: @Shawn good question. the database is created by perl tool, and I am building a GUI that nicely displays the DB and allow some modifications on it (enabling/disabling stages for example). I prefer to use python for gui (I chose pyqt5 for that task)